# How can I give if else if statement inside a AsEnumerable select

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to give a conditional statement inside AsEnumerable select list. I have the following AsEnumerable  select . Here I am trying to give the condition  If IsRoleClocking = true then IsClockingEnabled  should be true else the value of IsClockingEnabled must be depends the value of (Convert.ToInt32(row["IsClockingEnabled"]) . Please help to amend the existing code to consider IsRoleClocking also.

```
bool IsRoleClocking = true;

attendanceEntry.attendanceLogList = dt.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(row =>
       {
         var p = new AttendanceLogModel
         {
                     
           IsFlexibleDayOff = (Convert.ToInt32(row["IsFlexibleDayOff"]) == 1) ? true : false,
           IsClockingEnabled = (Convert.ToInt32(row["IsClockingEnabled"]) == 1 ) ? true : false,
           IsProtected = (Convert.ToInt32(row["IsProtected"]) == 1) ? true : false,                        

         };
                    return p;
                })
                .ToList<AttendanceLogModel>();

            return attendanceEntry;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question correctly :)

Does this help?

```cs
IsClockingEnabled = IsRoleClocking ? true :
                    (Convert.ToInt32(row["IsClockingEnabled"]) == 1 ) ? true : false;
```

**update**

Just noticed, it can be done much simpler:

```cs
IsClockingEnabled = IsRoleClocking || Convert.ToInt32(row["IsClockingEnabled"]) == 1;
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect Many Thanks